# RegExing a RegEx Expression: An Escape Issue?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I deal with a lot of regular expressions in my day job. Strange as it may sound, sometimes I even use RegEx to edit/fix/format my RegEx expressions. However, this is one problem that is bugging the heck out of me. How do I properly catch escaped characters, and only those that are truly escaped?

A list of strings:

```
this is a test
this is a te\st
this is a te\\st
this is a te\\\st
this is a te\\\\st
this is a te\\\\\st
this is a te\\\\\\st
```

If I wanted to match only those where the 's' was (or was not) a character class (i.e. space), how would I do this?

Explained:

```
this is a test       = test
this is a te\st      = te \s t
this is a te\\st     = te \\ st
this is a te\\\st    = te \\ \s t
this is a te\\\\st   = te \\ \\ st
this is a te\\\\\st  = te \\ \\ \s t
this is a te\\\\\\st = te \\ \\ \\ st
```

You cannot simply use a `[^\\]s` or `(?<!\\)s`. I've tried multiple combinations, with no success. How do I catch:

```
this is a test
this is a te\\st
this is a te\\\\st
this is a te\\\\\\st
```

And/or the opposite:

```
this is a te\st
this is a te\\\st
this is a te\\\\\st
```

Variations I've tried. . .

```
.*(?<=(?<!\\)(?<=(\\\\)+))st.*
.*((?<=(?<!\\)(\\\\)+)|(?<!\\))st.*
```

**EDIT:** This needs to be a dynamic length.

Comment: I think you want a negative lookbehind with `[^\\](\\\\)*`

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this to get all the 'true' `s`:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\.|[^\\\n])*?(s)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yA2mU1)

And something like that to get all the escaped `s`:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\.|[^\\\n])*?(\\s)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nZ2iE5)

Comment: Second one works, but not the first for me. First is returning ALL strings.

Comment: @J-Law Are you not trying to match the literal `s`? If not, what are you exactly looking for?

Comment: I am wanting a method to catch literals, and a method to catch non-literals ('escaped `s`'). Your non-literal (i.e. your second expression) works great. However, the literal (i.e. the first one) is not. But I'll take having at least half of it being right :)

Comment: @J-Law If the regex engine supports variable width lookbedhinds, you can put the whole `(?<!\\)(?:\\.|[^\\\n])*?` part in a positive lookbehind to match only the part you want to. Otherwise, you'll get the part you want to match in a capture group.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have capture group availability in this case, but yes, in an ideal world, this would work.

Comment: @J-Law You can use variable width lookbehinds in .NET regex engine. Otherwise, I don't see any way to get what you're looking for without a capture group. Any reason why you don't have access to the capture group? Maybe explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have multiple uses for this. 

Google Doc Spreadsheet, `REGEXREPLACE()` function. 
Custom PHP RegEx tester. 
MySQL `RLIKE`. 
Linux `.nanorc` color configuration. 

Uses are endless, but if possible, I'd like to find one that is as compatible as it can be.

Comment: Change the first to `((?<!\\)(?:\\.|[^\\\n])*?(\\\\s)|(^|[^\\])s)t` I realized that I made the dumb mistake of using 's', since it already exists elsewhere in the string (hence the added `t` at the end).

Comment: @J-Law Huh, but it's still using capture groups.

Comment: I may be missing part of the definition to a capture group. To my understanding, a capture group uses a `(`capture group `)` to return an array of matched results, which can also be used in conjunction with `\0`, `\1`, `\2`, etc. However, I am not utilizing `\1` inside or outside of the regex, that I see.

Comment: @J-Law That's partly what are capture groups, yes, but you don't need to reference them to have capture groups. You have a capture group as soon as you use `( ... )`. Those count as match as well and as a result, your regex would also match 'all strings'. Or I missed something somewhere :?

Comment: Touche. Definitions are not my strong suit :-\ I am able to use a `\0` capture group for search functionality, but if it cannot be used in a regex tester, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex-engine supports unbounded lookbehind, you can write:

```
(?<=(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)\\s
```

to match `\s` that is preceded by start-of-string-or-a-non-backslash-character plus an even number of backslashes.

But the approach I usually use is to match *either* `\\` *or* whatever escape sequence I'm interested in, and then write a replacement expression that works for both cases. For example, in JavaScript:

```
var result =
     input.replace(/\\[\\s]/g, function ($0) {
         if ($0 === '\\\\') {
             return '\\\\';
         } else {
             ...
         }
     });
```